# mongoDB: is it better to remove a field to nullify it?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

I would like to know which is better for an existing document: To remove a field to nullify it, or to keep the field and simply set it to null?

I'd also like to know more about the process of saving the document: Will the document be saved in the same place or will an entirely new document be saved somewhere else on the disk?

**Note:** *This question has absolutely nothing in common with "Is shortening MongoDB property names worthwhile?"! I'm asking about saving a record that already exists by removing a field instead of nullifying it.*

Comment: Will any of your queries be filtering on if this field is present?

Comment: yes, but i can do simply myField:Null and it's will also take in account not existing field ..